# Optimization Calculus - Largest rectangle that can be inscribed in an ellipse

Tags: calculus, optimization

A geometry student wants to draw a triangle inscribed in the ellipse $x^2+4y^2=16$. What is the area of the largest rectangle that the student can draw?

I know the final solution is $16$, but I am not sure of how to get that answer.

Comment: Triangle or rectangle?  Please proof-read your question carefully before posting.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that your receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.